Is there a way to achieve a long jet of air?
As can be seen in the image bellow from a fog/smoke generator machine, the smoke spreads as soon as it leaves the nozzle.

(source)
Is there a way to achieve a longer jet of air with less dissipation similar to a laminar flow water jet?

(source)

No, not really. Your water jet is not a laminar flow. It's a column of fluid in a medium of lesser density. If you try that with water in water you will also not get such a long and narrow flow pattern. If you want separate flow to a well defined volume you have to use a pipe.

Not a jet, but it is possible to send air with momentum with low dissipation via vortex rings, see e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yjgACB7urOo .

You'd have to find a way to maintain a low Reynolds number ($\text{Re}$) as the jet progresses.
$$\text{Re} = \frac{\rho u L} {\mu}$$
$\rho$ being density, $u$ being fluid speed, $L$ is the characteristic length, and $\mu$ the dynamic viscosity. The longer the jet is ($L$) the higher the change of developing turbulence and spreading. You could try an extremely low fluid speed, or have the jet be surrounded by a much less dense or viscous fluid.
